# Does re-writing the same value to a memory location count as modifying the memory? (in the context of multi-threading)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-model, data-race

*(Assume: `int x{ 6 }` and 2 evaluations write `x = 6` at the same time)*

--

CPP reference says on [Memory model: Threads and data races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model):

> When an *evaluation of an expression **writes** to a memory location* and
> *another evaluation **reads** or **modifies** the same memory location*, the
> expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting
> evaluations has a data race unless:
>
> - both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal
>   handler, or
> - both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see
>   std::atomic), or
> - one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before
>   another (see std::memory_order).
>
> If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined.

The reference says: *"another evaluation **modifies**"*; It does not say *"another evaluation **writes**"*.

--

C++ standard says on [6.9.2.2 Data races](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-2):

> 2. Two expression evaluations conflict if *one of them **modifies*** a memory location ([intro.memory]) and *the other one **reads** or
>    **modifies*** the same memory location.

--

Does re-writing the same value to a memory location count as modifying the memory?

Comment: Hmm. How would that "other evaluation" know that it's writing the same value unless it first **reads** it ... and that would (by the argument of the citation you quote) already have caused a conflict.

Comment: Although I agree the wording is a bit unclear, I *think* the use of the term, "modifies" is here intended to cover both 'normal' writes (e.g. `i = 3`) and other forms of modification (e.g. `++i`).

Comment: @AdrianMole, I inquired of both ChatGPT and Bard: While ChatGPT states it doesn't count as, Bard argues that it does indeed count as. However, I place no trust in either of their perspectives.

Comment: The [Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-2) doesn't use 'write' in this context, at all: *Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location ([intro.memory]) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.*

Comment: I would say that the term, "modifies" is a superset of "writes", though I can't find any formal definition of what is meant by either in the Standard. In normal, 'human' usage, overwriting a value with the same value isn't considered modification but, in computer programming, I would argue that it is. The Standard doesn't have any concept of *actual* hardware but, when writing a value to an `int` location, the CPU typically places a 'write lock' on the memory before sending the 'new' data.

Comment: You used chatGPT to get answers to C++, no don't it gets really confused on all the C++ details. (Often mixes op "C" and "C++" and even C#)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, not in order to get a solid knowledge - just get, MAYBE, a lead.

Comment: The safest approach would be to assume it is. Comparing the value before writing will introduce a race for sure (unless you force locking read/write manually).  I am more curious what the question/problem behind your question is? Do you experience performance issues with a lock?

Comment: @Amit I think it is still as likely it will lead you in the wrong direction. But well, you ended up here anyway ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does writing the same value to a memory location count as modifying the memory?

Yes, for example simple assignment to a scalar object (which is what a *memory location* actually is with exceptions for bit fields) is defined to *modify* the object regardless of the value that the object is being changed to. See [[expr.ass]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ass#2):

> 2. In simple assignment (=), the object referred to by the left operand is **modified** ([defns.access]) by replacing its value with the result of the right operand.

You find similar wording for all other expressions that affect the value of a scalar object.

---

Regarding terminology, the standard usually doesn't use "*write*", it uses "*modify*" with the same meaning instead. See e.g. [[defns.access]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.defs#defns.access).

Comment: You are right. I fixed the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model page accordingly. Now it is: "When an evaluation of an expression modifies a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict."

Comment: @Amit I should have been a bit more careful with that. The standard also sometimes uses "write", but I think that is just being inconsistent. E.g. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.races-7.2.

Comment: When the terms 'writes' and 'modifies' appear together in a sentence, it suggests a distinction between the two terms.

Comment: @Amit I agree with your change.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that *modifying* means that any write access to an object takes place.
Even if this doesn't change any bits in memory, it does modify the value in the abstract C++ sense.

You can run into data race by modifying memory in the abstract C++ sense, even if this modification doesn't change any bits in memory.

### The long answer

To get a clearer picture, refer to the [C++11 standard, [intro.multithread] p21](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.multithread#21):

*Note: I'm citing C++11 because this is a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) question.*

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

The relevant wording is *conflict*, defined in [[intro.multithread] p4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.multithread#4):

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies ([intro.memory]) a memory location and the other one accesses or modifies the same memory location.

Unfortunately, this is where things get unclear, because "modify" isn't actually defined in the standard; it's not defined in [[intro.defs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.defs).

#### The most plausible interpretation

[Edit 3470](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3470) clarified what *accessing* means in a number of places. To *access* means to read or modify a value.
The current definition of *confict* also uses this "read or modify" terminology, in [[intro.races] (working draft)](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:conflict).

The way that "access" and "read or modify" are used in the standard usually doesn't require values to compare unequal before/after for a modification to take place.

- you violate strict aliasing if you modify something through the wrong type, even if no bits in memory are changed, and
- by the same logic, you modify a value even if you don't change any bits in memory, and can run into a data race.

#### Further thoughts on values and modifications

Also note that in the working draft (although not in C++11), assigning always modifies the value as per [[expr.ass] p2 (working draft)](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#2):

> In simple assignment (`=`), the object referred to by the left operand is modified ([defns.access]) by replacing its value with the result of the right operand.

It's not required that the new value compares unequal to the old value. The object is always modified.

##### You can change bits without any observable change in value

```cpp
0 == 0; // guaranteed true, because zero compares equal to zero
int x = 0;
x = 0; // if int is padded, then this might modify padding bits of int
       // even though the values compare equal before and after, bits are changed
```

##### You can change values without changing any storage bits

Also note that *value* typically refers to the state of an object. Two values are distinct, even if they compare equal:

```
int x; // x has no value, but all of the bits in the storage could be zero here
std::construct_at(&x); // x now has value zero, and while this does change its value
                       // (it was indeterminate before), it might not have any affect
                       // on the bits of its storage
```

As you can see, changing bits in memory is a separate concept from modifying a value.
Assignment *always* changes the value.

Comment: I think that (as user17732522 quoted) "In simple assignment (=), the object referred to by the left operand is modified ([defns.access]) by replacing its value with the result of the right operand." concludes that any **simple assignment** (regardless the before/after values) is considered a **modification**.

Comment: @Amit you're right about that. The quote is already included in my answer, and I do mention at the end that all assignment counts as a modification.